# Passing the parameters in actions vector of transaction struct

Tags: smart-contract, transactions

In the below code, I am passing parameters to actions struct which takes account_name, action_name, permission vector and arguments. But while sending the account_name using `N` it is taking the exact value of account i.e. `account_name` not what is the value of this variable. I tried using hard coding the account_name and it worked. 

So, the question is how to send the account_name as variable while setting the actions in a transaction.


`void send(account_name account, std::string message) { 
    eosio::transaction t{};
    t.actions.emplace_back(
        eosio::permission_level(account, N(active)),
        N(account), // right now it is sending account as it is, not the value that it contains i.e. eosio
        N(action), // works fine for this
        std::make_tuple(message)
    );
}`

Comment: just use `account` instead of `N(account)`

Comment: Worked. Thanks! But I am confused about the permissions now. In above code, we have to pass the account_name at three different places. 1-in permission_level vector, 2-the second argument and 3-in t.send(). Can you explain me what permissions are these and which account_name i should use and when. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, the question is how to send the account_name as variable while setting the actions in a transaction.

`N(account)` is a preprocessor macro defined [in the `eosio` codebase](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/9be89106da1d6a1543eb19dd0f3b96a53e286088/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/name.hpp#L21-L38) to convert the literal string `"account"` into an `uint64_t` based on its base32 representation. So, in your case, you only have to use `account` (which is already `uint64_t`) instead of `N(account)`.

In the comments, you asked:

> In above code, we have to pass the account_name at three different places. 1-in permission_level vector, 2-the second argument and 3-in t.send(). Can you explain me what permissions are these and which account_name i should use and when

As far as I know, there's not much documentation on this, but my understanding is as follows (someone please correct me if I'm wrong):

- The `account` in `permission_level` is the account whose permissions are needed to send the action, so you would use the account that would give permission when calling the action
- The second argument is the account to which the action is sent, so you just use the receiver `account_name`
- The third `account` is the payer for the transaction for CPU/NET, and this is also contextually chosen based on the service, but typically the same as the account in the first argument (or `_self` if the contract pays themselves)